# How to include an icon in the title bar of window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to be able to replace the existing standard icon with my own but I am unsure how to do so. I only started Qt one week ago so I don't know much about the application. In addition to this I looked at the Qt website but their method for adding an icon did not work on my computer.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please add the code that you've tried and didn't work.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/appicon.html I tried this method yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using a RC file (Windows) you may specify the icon directly using **qmake**.

```
win32: RC_ICONS = icon.ico
```

Make sure it detects the path correctly. In the provided case the icon resides in the project root directory right beside the project file.

---

For window icons you typically, if application wide applicable, use some method of `QApplication`.

```
...
QApplication app(argc, argv);
...
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icon");
...
```

which is consuming the resource file using the alias *icon*. Here is an example (*res.qrc*):

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="icon">icon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

More information on resources are [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the function [setWindowIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop) function on the QWidget or QApplication.