# how to add a header to a QMainWindow before the Menu Bar section?

Tags: c++, qt

According to `QMainWindow` class description, the `QMainWindow` layout is:

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to add a header or toolbar before the Menu Bar section?

Something like this:

[image]

My first approach is as follows:

```
auto headerWidget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *headerLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
headerWidget->setLayout(headerLayout);

// Header section
QWidget *descWidget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *descLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
descWidget->setLayout(descLayout);

auto titleLabel = new QLabel("Title");
descLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);

headerLayout->addWidget(descWidget); // add the description widget to the headerLayout

setMenuWidget(headerWidget);
```

I don't know how to add the menus to the `headerLayout`.

The code to create a MenuBar is the following:

```
// Menus
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
fileMenu->addAction(openAct);
fileMenu->addAction(saveAct);
fileMenu->addSeparator();
fileMenu->addAction(exitAct);

editMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Edit"));

viewMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&View"));
optionsMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Options"));

helpMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Help"));
helpMenu->addAction(aboutAct);
```

Is there a way to add the `QMenu` to the `headerLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I think QMenu is a subclass of QWidget, so you can add QMenu to a layout like other QWidgets.

official doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmenu.html

By the way , why not modify title bar of mainwindow to show the project name,version and icon?

```
QMainWindow w;

w.setWindowTitle(QString("project name version"));
```

and

[How to include an icon in the title bar of window in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530509/how-to-include-an-icon-in-the-title-bar-of-window-in-qt)

Comment: The OP is asking about QMenuBar, not QMenu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot break `QMainWindow`'s layout, you can only use it as it is, meaning you cannot add a widget above its menu bar.

My solution is to not use its menu bar, but to make my own, and add it to the `centralWidget`, and use the `menuWidget` as the header you need.

Minimal Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow mainWindow;

    QWidget headerWidget;
    QHBoxLayout headerLayout(&headerWidget);

    headerWidget.setStyleSheet("background: darkgreen;");

    QLabel label("Project Name & version");
    QLabel ico;
    QImage icon(":/Resources/Images/icon.png");
    icon = icon.scaled(50,50);

    ico.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(icon));

    headerLayout.addWidget(&label);
    headerLayout.addWidget(&ico);

    QMenuBar menuBar;
    menuBar.setStyleSheet("background: darkblue;");

    QMenu menu("menu");
    menuBar.addMenu(&menu);

    mainWindow.setMenuWidget(&headerWidget);

    QWidget centralWidget;
    QVBoxLayout vLayout(&centralWidget);

    centralWidget.setStyleSheet("background: white;");
    vLayout.setMenuBar(&menuBar);

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(&centralWidget);
    mainWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image: Custom main window layout]

The white part is the `centralWidget`, which includes the blue menu bar.

You can see that I am not using another widget inside my header, `headerWidget` seems to be enough for a container. I applied an H layout to it, and just added some labels for demonstration.

You can add all the menus and actions you need to `menuBar` (the `QMenuBar` I'm using in the `centralWidget` as the `mainWindow`'s menu bar).

**Inspiration:** [Qt Forum: Add QWidget above QToolBar in QMainWindow](https://forum.qt.io/topic/110909/add-qwidget-above-qtoolbar-in-qmainwindow/2)

**Credit:** [Chris Kawa](https://forum.qt.io/user/chris-kawa)